# Unnest daframe within tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm not sure how to create a reproducible dataset based on this situation. But below is the output from `glimpse`, where glimpse identifies 2 columns with `item` column is a `data.frame` object.

What I want is to have a rectangular tibble, which if `item` was just another `tibble`, I can simply `unnest`.

```
> glimpse(df)
Columns: 2
$ ID   <chr> "A", "B", "C", "D", 
$ item <df[,2]> <data.frame[25 x 2]>

> df
# A tibble: 149,826 x 2
   ID        item$link                                    $value             
   <chr>     <chr>                                        <chr>              
 1 A~ https://ex.com/api/now/                          941b821e6f9121004d
 2 B~ https://ex.com/api/now/                          6c5bdbd46fa9610080
 3 C~ https://ex.com/api/now/                          941b821e6f9121004d
```

The current workaround I use is by converting the `data.frame` column as tibble and bind it back to the rest of the table. But this is not ideal if I have many columns with this `data.frame` type. Notice how the important column identifier which is `item` is now lost as it only captures `link` and `value`.
If there're multiple columns with `data.frame` type, this will generate an error since these columns will all be called `link` and `value`.

```
df <- bind_cols(df %>% dplyr::select(ID), as_tibble(dataset$item))

> df
# A tibble: 149,826 x 3
   number    link                                         value              
   <chr>     <chr>                                        <chr>              
 1 A~ https://ex.com/api/now/                          941b821e6f9121004d
 2 B~ https://ex.com/api/now/                          6c5bdbd46fa9610080
 3 C~ https://ex.com/api/now/                          941b821e6f9121004d
```

Comment: I am not sure what your desired output is. I've outlined one possible approach below in my answer, but let me know if you are looking for a different output.

Comment: @TimTeaFan your answer was good, accepted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach below can solve your problem. Please see the inline comments.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

# a data.frame
dat1 <- data.frame(link = rep("https://ex.com/api/now/", 3),
                   value = c("941b821e6f9121004d",
                             "6c5bdbd46fa9610080",
                             "941b821e6f9121004d"))
# another data.frame
dat2 <- data.frame(link = rep("https://another/link", 3),
                   value = c("843rq4nrfhvr843938",
                             "35rth165bft1tsv15d",
                             "435grg53th1ht51gte"))

# the example data containing two columns which are data.frames
dat <- tibble(id = c("A","B", "C"),
              item1 = dat1,
              item2 = dat2)

# lets have a look
dat %>% glimpse
#> Rows: 3
#> Columns: 3
#> $ id    <chr> "A", "B", "C"
#> $ item1 <df[,2]> <data.frame[3 x 2]>
#> $ item2 <df[,2]> <data.frame[3 x 2]>

# use chop to bring the data.frame columns in a nested format
dat_chop <- dat %>% chop(c(item1, item2)) 

# if you need one specific colum just unnest it:
dat_chop %>% unnest(item1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   id    link                    value                       item2
#>   <chr> <chr>                   <chr>              <list<df[,2]>>
#> 1 A     https://ex.com/api/now/ 941b821e6f9121004d        [1 × 2]
#> 2 B     https://ex.com/api/now/ 6c5bdbd46fa9610080        [1 × 2]
#> 3 C     https://ex.com/api/now/ 941b821e6f9121004d        [1 × 2]

# if you need all columns, unnest it and specify a `names_repair` strategy:
dat_chop %>%
  unnest(c(item1, item2), names_repair = "universal") %>%
  # the above will suffice if you don't mind:
  # (1) the dots `...` in the column names
  # (2) the consecutive numbering of the variables
  # both can be changed with the following call to `rename_with`
  rename_with(~ str_replace_all(.x, "\\.\\.\\.", "") %>%
                str_replace_all(., "\\d$",
                                function(x) ((as.numeric(x)%/% 2))),
              .cols = -id)
# Now each number refers to the item number it originated from!

#> New names:
#> * link -> link...2
#> * value -> value...3
#> * link -> link...4
#> * value -> value...5
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   id    link1                value1           link2              value2         
#>   <chr> <chr>                <chr>            <chr>              <chr>          
#> 1 A     https://ex.com/api/… 941b821e6f91210… https://another/l… 843rq4nrfhvr84…
#> 2 B     https://ex.com/api/… 6c5bdbd46fa9610… https://another/l… 35rth165bft1ts…
#> 3 C     https://ex.com/api/… 941b821e6f91210… https://another/l… 435grg53th1ht5…
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>